# VBA editor uses wrong language (German)

Tags: excel, vba, settings, vbe

In Excel, the VBA editor uses German instead of English and I have tried various things to try and change it, such as repairing Office 365 and checking the default language settings, without success. Is there a setting in Excel or VBA which controls this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513747/changing-language-of-visual-basic-editor-to-english

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded English United States and it worked. Uk didn’t work for some reason that it jumped to the next language in the list